# Android layout issue, text with image on the corner

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a very simple layout requirement for my Android Activity but I can't figure out how to translate it to xml: I just want the page to be filled with text (like a story, with no particular breaks at fixed places), plus an image on the upper-right corner, such that the text does not overlap with the image, but it should cover all the space which is not covered by the image. Does anybody know how to accomplish this? I tried playing around with a TextView and an ImageView, however this seems to require that the TextView occupies a non-rectangular region which I don't know how to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any reasonable way to do that in a Layout.

Have you considered using a WebView and doing this in HTML?